# Angular 2 periodically refresh view

Tags: javascript, angular, model-view-controller, momentjs

I'm displaying a list of items with their relative creation dates using moment.js .fromNow() like so:

```
getRelativeDate(date: string): string {
  return moment(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').fromNow();
}
```

---

```
<div class="created">{{getRelativeDate(item.created)}}</div>
```

And here's what it looks like:

[image]
But unless I interact with the item somehow it stays the same after initial load, which makes sense, since data isn't changing, current time is.

How can I force-refresh these values? Every minute would suffice.

Comment: This will depend on if your `item` data is async or not. You can create a `setInterval()` in `ngOnInit()` if the data is not async, if the data is async you can create the `setInterval()` after the data is fetched.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Surprised no one mentioned creating a pipe for this?

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

import moment from 'moment';

@Pipe({
  name: 'dateTimeFormat',
  pure: false,
})
export class DateTimeFormatPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(date: string, format: string = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'): string {
    return moment(date, format).fromNow();
  }
}
```

This keeps your component clean by offloading the logic into a Pipe.

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let date of dates">
    {{ date | dateTimeFormat:'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Whats cool is the format is optional and can be reused throughout your application.

Then to update the component periodically refresh call `setInterval`.
 You also need to invoke [ChangeDetectorRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef#detectChanges) and call `detectChanges` based on your `ChangeDetectionStrategy`. Better yet, [detach](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef#detach) the component completely.

**Live Example**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cli-moment-pipe

Helpful set of Moment Pipes
https://github.com/urish/angular2-moment/

Comment: This is the right answer. Can't believe I didn't think of it before! :D

Comment: Does `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` mean that it won't update view automatically on data change? Only when I run `detectChanges()`?

Comment: It will only update the view when changes to `@Input()` bindings are detected. Since there's no @Input() bindings in my example component the only time the component updates is when I manually call `detectChanges`.  An better approach would be to detach the component completely. This makes sure the entire application doesn't check for changes every time `setInterval` fires.  I've updated by answer.

Comment: Do you mean to detach the whole list (`ul`, in this example) or each item (`li`)? Because the former is hard to do, and the later will cause hundreds of timers running if I have a long list, no?

Comment: No, detach the component displaying the list.  Every time a setInterval occurs Angular will run change detection for the entire app. By detaching the component (see my stackblitz) it will not force the entire app to refresh

Answer (score 2):

Go with a `setInterval`.

We'll need the `ChangeDetectorRef` to do this.

```
import {OnInit, OnDestroy, ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core';

export class Listcomponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

   intervalHolder: any;

   constructor(private _changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
   }

   ngOnInit(): void {
     this.intervalHolder = setInterval(() => {
       // Let's refresh the list.
       this._changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
     }, 1000 * 60); // 1 minute
   }

   ngOnDestroy(): void {
      clearInterval(this.intervalHolder);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data isn't async you can create a `setInterval()` in your `ngOnInit()` and then clear it `ngOnDestroy()`. Assuming your created dates are stored in an array named `items` under key `created`:

**component.ts**

```
myFromNowInterval: any;
myFromNow = Array(this.items.length).fill('');

ngOnInit() {
  this.myFromNowInterval = setInterval( () => {
    this.items.forEach( (item, index) => this.myFromNow[index] = this.getRelativeDate(item) )
  }, 60000);
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  clearInterval(this.myFromNowInterval);
}
```

**component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="item of items; let i = index;">
  <div class="created">{{ myFromNow[i] }}</div>
</div>
```

This will update `myFromNow` array every minute, and aligns the index of your new array to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's sufficient to just put an observable interval on the component, to trigger change detection.

```
triggerCD$;

ngOnInit() {
  this.triggerCD$ = Observable.interval(60000)
}
```

Testing with this

```
<span>{{ now() }}</span>

now() {
  const now: any = new Date();
  return (now - this.start)
}
```

With no trigger, display does not change.
With trigger, now() updates on the template (although no direct link to trigger).